A proof of Konig's edge-coloring theorem
It is known that the convex hull of the characteristic functions of matchings in a bipartite graph is the polytope
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{E(G)}_{\ge 0}\mid \sum_{e\in E(G):v\in e}x_e\le 1 \text{ for every $v\in V(G)$} \}.$$
A proof of the fact that edge chromatic number $\chi'(G)=\Delta(G)$ for bipartite $G$ states like this: the vector $\frac{1}{\Delta(G)}\mathbf{1}$ is in the polytope so that it is a convex combination of matchings. "Each of these matchings should cover each maximum-degree vertices. So there exists a matching $M$ covering all maximum-degree vertices." Hence $\Delta(G-M)=\Delta(G)-1$ and one can apply induction.
I don't understand the argument in the quote. Can anyone explain a bit about it?

Could you provide the reference from which you got the quote from?
